# Is there a way to change user desktop directory path value in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I know there is NSDesktopDirectory that will get me the path to current user desktop directory, but where is this path value written and is there a way to change it from my cocoa application I cannot find out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Additional explanation:** in Snow Leopard when I rename Desktop folder to anything whatsoever, the content of this folder still shows on desktop, so I guess OS keeps track about that folder name and locations changes and keep it as desktop folder. Does anyone know how it does that?

Comment: So, essentially, you're looking for a way to move the user's home directory, right?

Comment: No :), I'm looking for a way to change what is displayed on user's desktop.

Comment: Just read your clarification. Guess then you don't want to change the home folder after all ;) If you want to change the folder that's used for the Desktop, one way that should work is to delete the original ~/Desktop folder (as root on the command line, since 10.6 prevents users from messing with these folders, and preferably while not logged in) and then symlink a different folder to ~/Desktop. I didn't test this, though.

Comment: I did and it does not work. But i don't wanna delete my old desktop. I'd like to be able to switch desktop folder to different folders according to selected project in my application. When user quits my application everything shoud turn back to normal.

Comment: @tmilovan Any application that could somehow manage to do such a thing as you describe would be in my trash the first time it did it. The Desktop belongs to the user. I strongly advise you to rethink your design.

Comment: Of course it does. That's why I'm trying to do desktop management application that will allow users to change the desktop folder according the project they are working on. That is trivial to do on linux with just bash fu, but that does not work on SL because SL somehow keeps track about original desktop folder and always displays its content. However, my question was is it possible and not should I do it :))?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but as for how the OS keeps track of the desktop folder: It probably uses an alias. Same way it keeps apps' Open Recent menus working even when the files have all been moved around.

Comment: Will try to look at that. Is it posible that SL at creating user account stores user system directories (applications, library, desktop, music etc...)as constants and that they are not changeable unless deleted?

Comment: While it's evil and should not be done, what prevents you from storing the whole set of files from the user's desktop (including .DS_Store) into a folder in your ~/Library/Application Support/ folder, then moving other files on the ~/Desktop? This should effectively "replace" the user's desktop. However, if you're really looking into dominating the user so completely, why use a half-ass solution? Just use a full-screen window and you can put anything you want on the "desktop"...

Comment: @phil: C'mon, you're sounding a bit ridiculous. He'd hardly be "dominating the user" by providing a tool that does this for a user to download *because the user decides he/she wants to do this*. Let's leave the User Morality and Responsibility According to Phil out of this technical discussion, shall we?

Comment: @joshua nozzi: the content of the desktop is managed by the user; I have seen many "ports" that insist on imposing their way of working. It wasn't clear from the description if this was a user-controlled utility or an actual app. If it is an app, it should not control the desktop IMHO. If it's a utility, it is understandable, but then wouldn't it duplicate the functionality of Spaces?

Comment: @phil: You're conflating the term "desktop here. Spaces gives you desktop "space" but your desktop files remain exactly in the same place in all spaces (ie, you can't have different files on different spaces' desktops). The OP is proposing swapping the sets of files in the Desktop folder as an additional (not competing) workflow solution. Interesting, IMO, given some people's use of the desktop as "my currently-active files" for ease of access.

Comment: @phil: (ran out of room) So I don't think it's unreasonable and certainly not forcing someone to do something if they're downloading it because they agree, "Hey, neat! I think I could use that." It's a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: @joshua nozzi: I think this is a case of "what are you really trying to do", and I assumed the worst. But I also gave a solution to show that I'm not just a pretentious prick ;-)

Comment: @phil Your suggestion was perfectly sound (and should've been posted as an answer). My only real complaint was the strong "won't someone PLEASE think of the USER?!" reaction that accompanied it. :-)

Comment: Been away for few days. In a meantime I have completely given up the path changing and I'm already developing the application that will move the files around. I've had some concerns about this approach but I found they could all be solved easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question: there is no way to change the desktop path in Snow Leopard or Lion (although you van read it). The only way to switch dasktops is moving the contents itself which can be done with a set of AppleScripts to some degree :(.

The other way is this app here :)):

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/projectdesktops/id499870251?ls=1&mt=12

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is by storing whole set of files from the user's desktop (including .DS_Store, which has positional/spatial information) into a folder in your ~/Library/Application Support/ folder, then moving other files on the ~/Desktop? This should effectively "replace" the user's desktop.

[Posted as an answer as suggested above]

Comment: That is exactly what I choose to go with in the end. So far so good :).

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 40 minutes researching this out of curiosity. Google is unhelpful in this particular scenario so I poked around my ~/Library folder. The path isn't stored anywhere there. I then dug around with command-line-fu to check flags and any other metadata I could find. Nothing helpful.

I think this is a built-in thing that uses file system references as opposed to hard-coded file paths (which is why its "Desktop" designation survives renaming). If you delete it, it creates a new one and stores the ref to that one. You'll not be able to swap it around.

I think Phil's comment is probably your best bet: move the contents of the folder rather than the folder itself. Here's my take on it:

~/Desktop/.myDesktop1 ... ~/Desktop/.myDesktop2 ... ~/Desktop/.myDesktop3

Perhaps even: ~/Desktop/.myappdesktops/1 ~/Desktop/.myappdesktops/2 ~/Desktop/.myappdesktops/3

If you move stuff into a dot-folder, it'll remain hidden but there. Active stuff stays in ~/Desktop as normal but each of your conceptual "Desktops" gets stored in a dot-file so it stays hidden.

**Caveat:** Time Machine. :-) Regardless of your approach, swapping out "sets" of files will potentially wreak havoc with any backup solution.

Comment: That said, OP, I'd be interested in trying your app. It sounds like an interesting idea. Ping me on Twitter (@jnozzi) or on my personal site (see my profile). :-)

Comment: As soon as I have my app developed into satisfactory shape I will contact you :)).  And I think I have an elegant solution for Time Machine and moving problems. Will see though :))

Comment: Just to note anyone interested: the app is now submitted to Mac App store for review, and separate demo will be available soon.